# uninitialized constant Settings Ruby 1.9.3-p125

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, config, ruby-1.9.3

I've upgraded my `.rvmrc` from `ruby-1.9.2-p290` to `ruby-1.9.3-p125` and cause `uninitialized constant Settings`

`config/initializers/rails_config.rb`

```
RailsConfig.setup do |config|  
  config.const_name = "Settings" 
end
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same error when I ran an old codebase tested on ruby 1.9.2 with ruby 1.9.3, upgrading the rails_config gem to the latest version fixed it for me.

```
bundle update --source rails_config
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :before_configuration, :yield => true do
  RailsConfig.setup do |config|
    config.const_name = "Settings"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this hack, obviously the behavior is better but the constant doesn't appear in applicaiton scope, just into configuration files :( i don't understand that...